# JavaScript: SyntaxError: Expected token 'in' (Safari)

Tags: javascript, jquery, safari, cross-browser

I have javascript code (with jquery library v3.1.1), which works fine on newest Chrome, Firefox, Edge Browsers. But it certainly is not working on Safari browser. Checked for v10.0.3 and v5.1.7.

The only error I see from console log is: `SyntaxError: Expected token 'in'`. The problem lines are:

```
var collapsenumber = jQuery.makeArray(document.getElementsByClassName("panel panel-default"));
for (let i = 0; i < collapsenumber.length; i++) {
*my.js:288SyntaxError: Expected token 'in'*
  $('#collapse' + i).on('shown.bs.collapse', function () {
     $('#s' + i).goTo();
   });
};
```

Is this a general problem of incompatibility with new jquery? Or I can change somehow only this part code to make it work?

Comment: Any change if you replace let with var?

Comment: `$('.panel .panel-default').on('shown.bs.collapse', function() { $('#s' + $('.panel .panel-default').index(this).index().goTo(); });`

Comment: Yep. There are changes indeed. So I need to to change this part somehow. Thanks.

Comment: replacing `let` to `var` and workaround with `index()` in inner function helped. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect Safari is behind is ES6 implementation.Since let is part of ES6 replace let with var.

```
for (var i = 0; i < collapsenumber.length; i++) {
```

Comment: Hmm, maybe you can help also to to change the code with var, that the 'i' variable can be seen in the second block, inside function()?